# universal dynamic_cast<void*> equivalent for polymorphic and not polymorphic types

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-cast

I am using `dynamic_cast<void*>` in a memory manager template to obtain the real address of the object. 
However `dynamic_cast` is not allowed for types that are not polymorphic.
Is there a more universal way or do I need two versions of the template?

Comment: There's an **implicit** conversion for any pointer-to-object type to *pointer to cv-qualified void*; however, it's not guaranteed to yield the "real address" (whatever that is). It is guaranteed by [conv.ptr]/2 that the resulting void pointer "represents the address of the same byte in memory as the original pointer value"

Comment: @DyP: That doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Xeo Huh? It helps converting a pointer-to-object to a pointer-to-void, if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @DyP: A `dynamic_cast<void*>` yields the address of the *most derived object* that the pointer points to.

Comment: You might be able to use a tag-dispatch-based approach with `std::is_polymorphic`, which either uses `dynamic_cast` or just `static_cast` for non-polymorphic types. Of course, this only works if you're fine with just the address of the current pointed-to object for non-polymorphic types.

Comment: @Xeo Yes, assuming the "real address" is the address of the most-derived object.

Comment: The problem is that you *can't* obtain the real address of an object that's not polymorphic. If you want your memory manager to be able to handle free requests for the middle of a block (Why? There's a reason why C++ makes that undefined for standard new/delete.) you'll have to give it the ability to look up an interior pointer in its own data structures.

Comment: To back up Sebastian, C++03's [expr.delete]/3 requires the operand to either have the same static type as created by the new-expression or have the type of a base class subobject AND have a virtual dtor. You'll also need a virtual dtor just for destructing the object if you only have a base class pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_polymorphic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic) to do a compile-time switch on the two possibilities.

Comment: It is not C11 nor boost project.

Comment: You could reimplement it yourself, it doesn't require compiler magic, just somewhat weird code.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: How'd you do that? Derive from the type with an empty class and check if the size of the derived class is bigger than that of the base class (implying an extra vtable pointer)?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Looks like the boost implementation relies on the extra size of a vtable (using `sizeof` of a type derived from the type to test).

Comment: @Xeo The Boost version first does an is_class check to filter out primitives. is_class<T> can be implemented by doing SFINAE on a template function that takes a pointer to a member of T. Then it derives two classes from T, one with a virtual function, the other without, and checks if they're the same size.

Comment: This is still not all that satisfying, since you can't deal reliably with subobjects of non-polymorphic objects, and perhaps private bases would cause a problem, too...

Comment: Yes, I pointed that out in a comment on the question. The whole premise seems misguided.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Ah, I see. I guess my way won't necessarily work because of padding or something?

Comment: @Xeo: No, because a derived class doesn't get its own vtable pointer.